# Cuando me aparece el modal e introduzco los datos, y le doy crear me crea la reseña doble, y no sé por qué

Tags: python, django

El proyecto consta del uso de un model User, un model PerfilDeUsuario con el fin de añadirle algunos campos extra a mi user. También un model reseña donde cada perfil de usuario puede dejar muchas reseñas y estoy ahora creando la parte de crear estas reseñas  desde un modal bootstrap pero cuando en el modal introduzco los datos y le doy crear me crea la reseña doble y no sé por qué.

```
class CrearResegna2(BSModalCreateView):

   template_name = 'Servicios/ModalCrearResegna.html'
   form_class = ResegnaForm2
   success_message = 'Success: Book was created.'
   success_url = "/Perfil/"

   def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = form
        usuario = self.request.user
        contenido = self.request.POST['contenido']
        autor = PerfilUsuario.objects.get(user_id=usuario.id)
        res = Resegna(autor_id=autor.id, contenido=contenido)   
        res.save()
        return self.success_message
```

Answer (score 0):

Recordemos que el `form_valid` realiza el guardado automáticamente, si tu le indicas  `res.save()` te va a realizar un guardado y posteriormente el form al detectar que todo esta correcto te lo va a realizar un segundo guardado

```
def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
    context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['form'] = form
    usuario = self.request.user
    contenido = self.request.POST['contenido']
    autor = PerfilUsuario.objects.get(user_id=usuario.id)
    res = Resegna(autor_id=autor.id, contenido=contenido)   
    return super(CrearResegna2, self).form_valid(form)
```

Solo eliminamos el save y solo te guardara una vez

Comment: ya trate pero si quito el save entonces no se guarda, y si se lo dejo me lo guarda doble

Comment: acabo de editar el return de mi respuesta intentalo de ese modo